# Change of to_f behavior in ruby 2.4

Tags: ruby

Upgraded ruby version to 2.4 from 2.3 and noticed some change in {{to_f}} functionality.  One of the change in behavior is

with 2.3 version

```
2.3.3 :001 > 
 '1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008'.to_f
=> 1.0 
2.3.3 :002 > 
'0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008'.to_f
=> 0.0
```

with 2.4.1 . version

```
 pry(#<001>)> 
"0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008".to_f
=> 8.0e-62
 pry(#<002>)> 
"0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008".to_f
  => 8.0e-63
 pry(#<004>)> '0.00000000000000000000000008'.to_f 
 => 8.0e-26
 pry(#<005>)> 
'0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008'.to_f
 => 8.0e-62
  pry(#<006>)> 
'1.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008'.to_f
 => 1.0
```

Can anyone help me in understanding why there is difference while performing `to_f` on 62 digits among both versions of ruby?

Comment: I can see a difference in the behavior of `Float#inspect` in your code, but there's nothing conclusive about `String#to_f`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Well in 2.3.3 doing `'0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008'.to_f == 0.0` is `true`, whereas in 2.4.2 it’s `false`. So it would seem the difference does lie either in `String#to_f` or in Float’s underlying precision.

Comment: Or in `Float#==`.

Comment: Using the literal number and comparing they’re unequal in 2.3 (`0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008 == 0.0`), so it’s probably not `Float#==`, and may be `String#to_f`. A brief perusal of changelogs and greping commits, etc. doesn’t yield anything interesting, though.